# Pagination в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Друзья помогите пожалуйста разобраться с пагинацией в Laravel 5, ни как не хочет работать нету классов для работы с Pagination.
Пробовал подключать:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator;`
`use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`
Ничего не помогает в провайдерах есть класс `Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider`, в алиасах нету класса Pagination

Comment: Покажите ваш контроллер, где вы используете пагинацию!

Comment: @Pearson  Я ее и не использую потому что у меня нет класса Pagination, как использовать то чего нету?

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = test::all()->paginate(10);
```

Попробуй